# Categorical crossentropy and label encoding

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

I'm trying to code multiclass output and classes are ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'].

Could someone elaborate more next error message:

"ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (79, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:

`from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)`

Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets."

My code:

```python
# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

# Importing the dataset
dataa = pd.read_csv('test_out.csv')

XX = dataa.iloc[:, 0:4].values
yy = dataa.iloc[:, 4].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_Y_1 = LabelEncoder()
yy = labelencoder_Y_1.fit_transform(yy)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(XX, yy, test_size = 0.2, 
random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Part 2 - Now let's make the ANN!

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', 
input_dim = 4))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, init = 'uniform', activation = 
'softmax'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 50)

# Part 3 - Making the predictions and evaluating the model

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Have you tried one of the things the error message tells you to do?

Comment: is your target class binary.?

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in this portion of your code,

```
# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_Y_1 = LabelEncoder()
yy = labelencoder_Y_1.fit_transform(yy)
```

You forgot to one-hot encode the `yy`, please take note that `LabelEncoder` only transforms your categorical data to numerical one, i.e. `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. You have to one-hot encode it since you want to use `softmax` activation, and `categorical_crossentropy` (I'm over-simplifying, but it's the gist).

So, it should have been like this,

```
# Encoding categorical data
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_Y_1 = LabelEncoder()
yy = labelencoder_Y_1.fit_transform(yy)
yy = to_categorical(yy)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your target class that you are going to predict is binary i.e there are only 2 possible values that could occur

If your target is binary then, the last layer of the model should be activated with `sigmoid` activation function. Also, the model should be compiled with `binary_crossentropy` or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

If the target is multi-class i.e more than 2 possible values, you must convert the target to categorical with the help of `to_categorical` from keras. Then you should compile your model with `categorical_crossentropy` and the last layer in the model should be activated with `softmax` activation function.!!

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this?